# WCF Service The request was aborted: The request was canceled

Tags: wcf, soap

I calling SOAP webservice in WCF service method.Sometimes,when method running,the error occurred the this method as following "The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)". How to resolve this error.Can you help me please?

Comment: You can't. Move it out of try statement and forget about it. It's all about connection issues.

Comment: which way you use to call the web service? there may be some errors occurred in the server end.